# Stat substitution command to capture numeric file permission in Solaris 10

Tags: permissions, solaris, stat

There is no stat command in Solaris 10. Is there any way to get numeric file permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU `stat` is available in the `SUNWgnu-coreutils` package. If you're not able to install that, the `pkgproto` command is an alternative.

From the manual page:

```
pkgproto /bin=bin /usr/bin=usrbin /etc=etc
   f none bin/sed=/bin/sed 0775 bin bin
   f none bin/sh=/bin/sh 0755 bin daemon
   f none bin/sort=/bin/sort 0755 bin bin
   f none usrbin/sdb=/usr/bin/sdb 0775 bin bin
   f none usrbin/shl=/usr/bin/shl 4755 bin bin
   d none etc/master.d 0755 root daemon
   f none etc/master.d/kernel=/etc/master.d/kernel 0644 root daemon
   f none etc/rc=/etc/rc 0744 root daemon
```

It's trivial to extract that output so that you just have the octal file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `lstat`, or `lstat64` if it is a 64-bit machine.

Comment: I believe the question related to the `stat` *command* and not the `stat` system call. `lstat` and `lstat64` are system calls, not commands.